# How to remove the first occurrence of a word with XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Given the following XML document:

```
<books>
  <book>
   <name>The problem of the ages</name>
  </book>
  <book>
   <name>Filtering the tap</name>
  </book>
  <book>
   <name>Legend of Atlantis</name>
  </book>
</books>
```

I want to remove the first "the" from the name of each book. Example of output:

```
<library>
  <record>problem of the ages</record>
  <record>Filtering tap</record>
  <record>Legend of Atlantis</record>
</library>
```

How would I achieve this using a single XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to decide what a word is, given the different languages that exist in a world. However, the regular expression language used in XSLT/XPath 2 and later allows you to match on `\w` alphanumeric letters so

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="word-to-eliminate" as="xs:string" select="'the'"/>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="book/name">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., $word-to-eliminate, 'i')" mode="eliminate-first"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:match[1]" mode="eliminate-first"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:non-match[preceding-sibling::node()[1][. is root()/descendant::fn:match[1]]]" mode="eliminate-first">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s', '')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

might help in XSLT 3 or could be achieve in a similar way in XSLT 2 using `xsl:analyze-string` instead.

Or, if any white space can be considered a word separator and in the result you only want a single space between the remaining words, then

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="word-to-eliminate" as="xs:string" select="'the'"/>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="book">
      <record>
          <xsl:value-of 
            select="analyze-string(name, '\s+')
                    !
                    (fn:non-match 
                     except 
                     fn:non-match[lower-case(.) = $word-to-eliminate][1]
                    )"/>
      </record>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am interested in the second case, as it seems simpler to understand. However, you say it applies if I "only want a single space between the remaining words". What if I want to preserve the number of spaces? As an example, removing the first 'the' from 'before<1space>the<1space>apple<2space>of<4space>the<1space>dragon' should result in 'before<2space>apple<2space>of<4space>the<1space>dragon'.

Comment: If the first case solves the problem then use it, don't expect a simpler solution for a simple problem to be adapted to a more complex requirement.

Comment: Also, I'd appreciate it if you could explain what `analyze-string(name, '\s+') ! (fn:non-match except fn:non-match[lower-case(.) = $word-to-eliminate][1] )` does.